# ctypes giving error on calling function with pointer to class object

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ctypes

I have two wrapper functions in my C++ DLL.

The function `CreateObj()` makes an object of some other class and returns a pointer to the object
In the second function `DoSomething` I pass the previously created pointer as first argument and the second argument is a  RGB image (1200, 1200,3) of unsigned chars.

On the python side I load the DLL and want to call the two wrapper functions to do some processing on a RGB image that I have loaded on the python side. I am getting an OSError in the very last step of calling `DoSomething` from python.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
//The C++ library code

class Obj
{
    /*..../*
};

extern "C"
{
#ifdef BUILD_AS_DLL
    __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
    Obj* CreateObj();
    int DoSomething( Obj* ptr,  uint8_t*  t[1200][1200][]);  //ptr was created using CreateObj and second argument is an image array of unsigned char of shape [1200][1200][3]
#ifdef BUILD_AS_DLL
    __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
}
```

The  Python code for calling the above DLL

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct
import cv2
    
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "mwe.dll") 
lib = ctypes.CDLL(path) 

create_func = lib.CreateObj
create_func.restype = c_void_p
obj = c_void_p(create_func())

dosomething_func = lib.DoSomething
ucharPtr = npct.ndpointer(dtype=np.uint8, 
                          ndim=3, 
                          shape = (1200,1200,3),
                          flags='CONTIGUOUS') 
dosomething_func.argtype = (c_void_p,
                            ucharPtr)
dosomething_func.restype = c_int

img = cv2.imread("path/to/image")  
img_ctype = byref(img.ctypes.data_as(c_void_p))
dosomething_func(byref(obj), img_ctype)   // ERROR on this line
```

I get error

```
File "mwe.py", line 24, in <module>
    res = dosomething_func(
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: Make a [mcve].  You can implement small, dummy C functions that accept the parameters you want and Python code that actually reproduces the failure against it and remove irrelevant code like importing an image...just create an array of the size you want to pass directly.  Your Python code references `seg` and doesn't define it.

Comment: i have addressed your comment.. seg was a typo

Comment: this was a minimal working example.. the DLL i made hade two exposed functions  `lib.CreateObj` and  `lib.DoSomething`. Please reconsider the downvote

Comment: Not really, it doesn't work to reproduce the error message.  Ideally, post the DLL code you actually wrote reduced to the minimal code to reproduce the exact problem.  Retyped partial code that isn't syntatically correct doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal reproducible example of a solution demonstrating passing a small 3D numpy array into and back out of a function:

test.cpp:

Note that `uint8_t*  t[1200][1200][]` was syntactically incorrect.  The variable array dimension must be first, not last, and this is an array of pointers not an array of 8-bit data.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define API __declspec(dllexport)

class Obj
{
    int m_x;
public:
    Obj(int x): m_x(x) {}
    int get_x() const { return m_x; }
};

extern "C" {

API Obj* CreateObj() {
    return new Obj(5);
}

API int DoSomething(Obj* ptr, uint8_t t[][3][3]) {
    for(uint8_t i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for(uint8_t j=0; j < 3; ++j) {
            for(uint8_t k=0; k < 3; ++k) {
                cout << static_cast<uint32_t>(t[i][j][k]) << ' ';
                t[i][j][k] *= 2;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return ptr->get_x();
}

}
```

test.py:

Assuming `cv2.imread()` returns an `np.array` of the same type and shape as the declared `ndpointer` type, you would just pass it to the function directly.

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct

lib = CDLL('./test')

class OBJ(Structure):
    _fields_ = []

ARRAY = npct.ndpointer(dtype=np.uint8,shape=(3,3,3))

lib.CreateObj.argtypes = c_int,
lib.CreateObj.restype = POINTER(OBJ)
lib.DoSomething.argtypes = POINTER(OBJ),ARRAY
lib.DoSomething.restype = c_int

arr = np.arange(27,dtype=np.uint8).reshape((3,3,3))
obj = lib.CreateObj(5)
result = lib.DoSomething(obj,arr)
print(f'result = {result}')
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8

9 10 11
12 13 14
15 16 17

18 19 20
21 22 23
24 25 26

result = 5
[[[ 0  2  4]
  [ 6  8 10]
  [12 14 16]]

 [[18 20 22]
  [24 26 28]
  [30 32 34]]

 [[36 38 40]
  [42 44 46]
  [48 50 52]]]
```